# Can't get if statement to compare two strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In my code when `i` equals 5 `myDate` should be equal to it. The alert shows me that they are the same. I can never get the function to `return 1;`

```
function checkForHoliday(date) {
    var myDate = new Date(date);
    myDate = myDate.getMonth() + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear();

    alert(myDate + "\n" + holidays[5]);

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
       if (myDate == holidays[i]) {
           return 1;
           alert("got it");
       }       
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is what the string in the array looks like:

```
year = 2013
holidays[5] = "7/2/" + year
```

My alert shows me this:
[image]

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: It looks like he's converting it to a string.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg it is a string. He overwrote it.

Comment: BTW, in the future I recommend using console.log for this kind of "printf debugging". Learning to use the development tools and debugger in your favourite browser also helps a ton.

Comment: You are returning 1 before you execute your alert statement. Try returning 1 after you do you alert so you can tell if your condition is met in the if statement.

Comment: OK, it is a string. Sorry. What about trimming the strings to get rid of possible space-characters?

Comment: I'd recommend you to convert the holidays and the dates to a unix timestamp and to compare them both like you're doing now, that way you won't have to mess with strings.

Comment: don't forget that `getMonth` starts at _zero_ for January...

Comment: "7/2/" ? it should be "8/2/"

Comment: I created a new variable to hold the string for comparing and it, that isn't a date, still wont say they are equal. I'm pretty sure I converted myDate to a string though. Okay I'll try the printf debugging.

Comment: "7/2" because months start at 0.

Comment: @TitanicSwimmer But you already hard-coded it as a string. If you pass in Date(), then you should consider 0-11 for month.

Comment: Thanks apfunk I guess it was working.

Comment: Why are you comparing years in your if statement when you are checking for holidays? Your code should work without `+ "/" + myDate.getFullYear()` and `/" + year` in the same way it does *(not)* work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run your code locally, and have it working.

I'm going to guess that your issue stems from the fact that Date.getMonth() returns month numbers where January === 0.  That throws a lot of people off.

To recreate your code, I simply used Chrome's console.  I also changed your alert to a `console.log` to save myself the hassle of using `alert`.

Here's the code:

```
function checkForHoliday(date) {
  var myDate = new Date(date);
  myDate = myDate.getMonth() + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear();

  console.log(myDate + "\n" + holidays[5]);

  for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (myDate == holidays[i]) {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And a fake holiday array:

```
holidays = [0,1,2,3,4,'7/2/2013']
```

(The 7 here actually corresponds to August)

Upon running `checkForHoliday('8/2/2013')`, the console reports back a response of `1`.  The code successfully matches the date.

If you actually intended for `holiday[5]` to represent July 2nd, 2013, you'll need to set `holiday[5] = '6/2/2013'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var startYear = parseInt(document.getElementById('startYear'), 10);
    var startMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById('startMonth'), 10) - 1; 
    var startDay = parseInt(document.getElementById('startDay'), 10);
    var myDate = new Date(startYear, startMonth, startDay);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date object to string in desired format. Use triple equals operator to test equality.

Try:

```
if (myDate.toLocaleDateString() === holidays[i]) {
    return 1;
    alert("got it");
}
```